# iOS PDF Forms & Reports

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

We are working on a solution that will require iOS to create PDF documents for various business transactions (i.e. sales orders, purchase orders, quotes, invoices, etc).

The underlying data that goes into the PDF documents are the same; however, many users will want their own company logo and most likely their own formatted layout.

We can ship the product with a default set of forms and a dynamic way to change the company logo but we're trying to identify a mechanism to custom design a form layout (using the same underlying data model) and somehow send/update/deliver to only the user who has paid for the custom form development.

Since the PDF generation process is objective c and I know apple doesn't allow us to download code after release I was wondering if anyone else had ideas on how to approach this issue.

EDIT: I'm looking to somehow modularize the code required for a PDF form layout.  Whether it's delivered via in-app purchase or by choosing from a list of files on our server isn't a huge concern.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Are you asking about payment verification, or how to insert the custom image(s)?

Comment: are you perhaps talking about in-app purchases?

Comment: not payment verification.... not inserting an image in a single PDF... but encapsulating the code/logic to create a PDF and making it deliverable in a payload of some sort to one or more target devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your form template in XML and then download these templates to your application. In your application you parse the XML and convert it to PDF drawing instructions.
For example your XML could look like this:

```
<form>
    <page width="612" height="792">
        <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="500" y2="20" />
    </page>
</form>
```

This XML would generate a PDF file with a single page with the size 612*792 points and the page content consists of a single horizontal line drawn from (20, 20) to (500, 20).
You can define your XML in any way you want so it fits best your needs.

Comment: Yes.. these kinds of ideas are what I'm looking for.  Thank you!